# Dominated convergence theorem (Folland's proof)

Tags: real-analysis, integration

The following is from Folland's real analysis p.55

[image]

I am confused about the following:

1. $\int g+\int f = \int (g+ f)=\int \text{lim inf}(g+f_n)\leq \text{lim inf} \int (g+f_n)$ (by Fatou).

If the above is true, how to say something about the second equality "$\text{lim inf} f_n=f$" where we just know $f_n \rightarrow f$ a.e. ?  If not true, how to fix it?

Comment: The set $\left\{x:\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)\ne f(x)\right\}$ has measure $0$. Thus we can integrate on the set $\left\{x:\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=f(x)\right\}$ and the integrals will be the same.

Comment: I am actually particularly confused about the " inf " in the second equality.

Comment: In Dominated Convergence we are given pointwise convergence (a.e.) and so $f(x)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)$ (a.e.)

Comment: Thanks, it makes much sense for me now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the measure of $N=\left\{x:\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)\ne f(x)\right\}$ is $0$, we can adjust $f_n$ on $N$ so that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=f(x)$ without changing any of the integrals.

[Dominated Convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) assumes pointwise convergence; thus, we have
$$
f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=\liminf_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)
$$